# Using Azure Mobile App service with existing SQL database

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, azure, xamarin

I have been trying to use the Azure SDK for mobile apps in order to enable offline sync. The issue is that I have an existing database currently in use with other applications.

So, I have been unable to make the modifications to the existing tables, such as altering the int primary id to an NVARCHAR GUID.

I have then followed other answers on here and various blogs and created a systems table for each table in the database and created a view for each table as well as triggers to handle the updates and deletes.

Following this approach, I have created a view for each table, but the table contains foreign keys, can I simply add each column on the related tables into one single view and handle the triggers and system table for each referenced table? Or is there more to it than that?

If there is an in depth documentation on existing databases with relationships, I have not seen it.

Answer (score 0):

During offline state in order to resolve an inmmediate conflict using GUID to instead of auto-incrementing integer id or integer id. GUID is stored as string during transfer.
We could find that Data Transfer Object (DTO) class that is used to define the table within the SQL database need to inherit from [EntityData](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt587298.aspx) class.But in your case is unable to make the modifications to the existing tables. In my Option, If we don't use a string id,it seems that we can't use offline sync.

More details please refer to [using an existing sql table](https://adrianhall.github.io/develop-mobile-apps-with-csharp-and-azure/chapter3/server/#using-an-existing-sql-table) and [relationships](https://adrianhall.github.io/develop-mobile-apps-with-csharp-and-azure/chapter3/relationships/).